# count pairs of non-crossing partitions that differ by one transposition

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

> ## **Problem:**
>
> $\sigma$ and $\delta$ are non-crossing partitions of $(1,2,\cdots,n)$. They only differ only by a single transposition. In another words, $\sigma \delta^{-1}$ is a single transposition.
>
> Let the number of pairs of $\sigma, \delta$ to be $a_n$. Find
>   an analytic expression for $a_n$.

**Example**:
When $n = 3$, we have 12 pairs:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sigma &= \left\lbrace
          \begin{aligned}
            &(123)&  \\
            & I&  \\
          \end{aligned} \right. 
\delta = \left\lbrace
         \begin{aligned}
          (12)  \\
          (13)  \\
          (23)
         \end{aligned} \right. 
\end{aligned}
+ \text{interchange} 
\end{equation}

Numerics suggests a surprisingly simple result
\begin{equation}
a_n = 2{2n \choose n - 2 }
\end{equation}
which makes me believe there is a simple proof.

### **non-crossing partition**

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation element which composes of cycles. We can draw it on a circle by connecting points within a circle. $\sigma$ is called a non-crossing partition if the resulting diagram has no intersection. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition) for more about its precise definition and properties.

For example, $\sigma = (13)2(456)$ is drew on the circle below, and it is a non-crossing partition. 
[image]

### Attempt:

Since non-crossing partition has orders, we can count the case of $\sigma > \delta$ and multiply by 2. This means that $\delta$ is a finer partition than $\sigma$, i.e. it can only break cycles inside $\sigma$.

Suppose $\sigma$ has $k$ cycles $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_k$. $\delta$ can be constructed by breaking any one of the cycles into two. Suppose cycle 1 has $|c_1| = m$ elements. Without loss of generality, let it be $(123\cdots m)$. There are ${m \choose 2 }$ ways for $\delta$ to break this cycle into two cycles, i.e. taking $1 \le i < j \le m$, $\delta = (ij) \sigma$. There are 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^k  { |c_i|  \choose 2 }
\end{equation}
ways to construct $\delta$ out of this $\sigma$. Hence
\begin{equation}
a_n = \sum_{\substack{\sigma \in \text{NC}\\ \sigma = \{c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_k \}}} \sum_{i=1}^k  { |c_i|  \choose 2 }
\end{equation}
I do not find a way to construct a recursive relation or generating function for $a_n $. It may be related to the free probability theory because it is a summation over the non-crossing partition lattice. But from what I know, the moment-cumulant relation in free probability is a summation over the *product* on the functions on each cycle, not a summation.

### Edit 11/10/2017:

According to the article [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition) and cited Kreweras's paper, there is a simple formula of counting the non-crossing partition according to cycle types.

Let $(r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n )$ be a set of non-negative integers that satisfy
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=1}^n m r_m = n 
\end{equation}
We can then use $r_m$ to denote the number m-cycles. The number of non-crossing partitions that has $r_m$ m-cycles ($m = 1, \cdots, n$) is
\begin{equation}
\frac{n!}{(n - \sum_m r_m +1 )!} \prod_m \frac{1}{r_m!} = \frac{1}{n+1} { n+1 \choose r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n } 
\end{equation}

Then 
\begin{equation}
a_n = \sum_{\{r_i\}} \frac{1}{n+1} { n+1 \choose r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n } \sum_{m=1}^{n} r_m { m \choose 2 } 
\end{equation}
where the summation is performed over the constraint $\sum_{m=1}^n m r_m = n$.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition) *Liaw, S.C.; Yeh, H.G.; Hwang, F.K.; Chang, G.J.*, [**A simple and direct derivation for the number of noncrossing partitions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-04546-8), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 126, No.6, 1579-1581 (1998). [ZBL0892.05007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0892.05007).

Comment: Is $\sigma\delta^{-1}$ a single transposition or does it just have one cycle?

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein, it is a single transposition. Thanks for correcting me. I have edited the post.

Comment: The formulation in terms of permutations is confusing, since a partition element is unordered but a permutation could traverse a cycle in either clockwise or counterclockwise order. I assume you intended to require a counterclockwise traversal.

Answer (score 1):

First, apply the bijection from noncrossing partitions of size $n$ to Dyck paths of order $n$, where for each vertex in order we write

- ${↗↘}$ if it’s not connected,
- ${↗↗}$ if it’s connected only to following vertices,
- ${↘↗}$ if it’s connected to a preceding vertex and a following vertex,
- ${↘↘}$ if it’s connected only to preceding vertices.

(Your example partition $(13)2(456)$ is written $↗↗↗↘↘↘↗↗↘↗↘↘$.)

Under this bijection, a single-transposition pair $σ, δ$ corresponds precisely to a pair of Dyck paths where we swap a matched $↗, ↘$ pair of nonzero height, or a $↘, ↗$ pair that would become matched; that is,

$$a_L{↗}b{\color{red}↗}c{\color{red}↘}d{↘}a_R \\
a_L{↗}b{\color{red}↘}c{\color{red}↗}d{↘}a_R$$

where $a_La_R, b, c, d$ are four Dyck paths, or the opposite. Breaking a cycle swaps a $↗$ at an even position with a $↘$ at an odd position, while joining two cycles swaps a $↗$ at an odd position with a $↘$ at an even position.

We can count these pairs as follows. Consider any staircase path $e$ (not a Dyck path) with $n + 2$ $↗$s and $n - 2$ $↘$s. Split it into $e_L{↗}e_R$ at the last $↗$ of minimum height. Then $e_R{↘↘↘}e_L$ is a Dyck path. We can let $a_R = e_L$, decompose $e_R$ uniquely as $a_L{↗}b{↗}c{↗}d$ where $b, c, d$ are Dyck paths, then plug $a_L, b, c, d, a_R$ into the above schema and its opposite. This construction gives each valid pair exactly once, so there are $2\binom{2n}{n - 2}$ of them.